# Linux UDP Socket sendto: Operation not Permitted

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, sip

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with the [OpenSIPS](http://www.opensips.org/) ( a SIP proxy ) application.

When sending two different UDP packets to the same IP and port, one call fails with  `-1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)` whilst the other is fine.

Both of the calls are made from the same process ( at least the same PID ).

The code in question is [on github](https://github.com/OpenSIPS/opensips/blob/master/udp_server.c#L459).

Here's the strace output:

```
strace -e sendto
sendto(7, "SIP/2.0 100 Giving a try\r\nVia: S"..., 315, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5060), sin_addr=inet_addr("yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy")}, 16) = 315
sendto(7, "INVITE sip:myHomeDesktop@xxx"..., 1253, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5060), sin_addr=inet_addr("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")}, 16) = 1253
sendto(7, "SIP/2.0 200 OK\r\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP"..., 707, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5060), sin_addr=inet_addr("yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy")}, 16) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Comment: Any clues if you trace your packets with wireshark ? e.g. any ICMP messages ?

Comment: Unfortunately there were no ICMP messages coming back. The tcpdump doesn't show the packet that failed to send going out either, but I suppose that's not surprising.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that the kernel conntrack modules were dropping the packet, leading to the syscall getting the EPERM error and not sending the packets.

I found this after looking at the syslog and finding:

```
May 26 10:59:45 localhost kernel: nf_ct_sip: dropping packet: cannot add expectation for voice
```

I was completely unaware that I was using the sip conntrack module, and it's not dynamically loaded on my system (`lsmod` shows blank).

I circumvented the problem by turning off connection tracking for my SIP traffic with:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -t raw -p udp --sport 5060 -j CT --notrack
iptables -I PREROUTING -t raw -p udp --dport 5060 -j CT --notrack
```

Comment: *conntrack* is the keyword. Thank you, saved a lot of time!

Comment: According to the manual `-j CT --notrack` can be replaced by `-j NOTRACK`